# HttpClient setting base address not working dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, httpclient

Hello so I'm trying to add my api with httpclient as a dependency injection and changing the baseaddress in the program.cs file here the code for adding it the container. I found other post regarding this and followed them but none worked and was wondering if I am doing something totally wrong here. trying to learn how injections work. Thank you.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ProductApi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7023/api/");
});
```

here is the code inside the blazor component

```
    private async Task GetProduct()
    {
       // ProductApi.BaseAddress =  new Uri ("https://localhost:7023/api/");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await ProductApi.GetAsync("Product");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<ProductModel>>();
                products = responseData;
            } 
     
    }
```

I tried looking up vidoes and other post about this issue. none worked for me I also have in the blazor code at the top @inject HttpClient ProductApi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're doing something wrong. To use an HTTP Client you can either use a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typed-clients) or a [named client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#named-clients). You are using a named client here since you register the client using a the string `ProductApi` but it seems you want to use it as if it was a typed client. Since it's not a typed client injecting `HttpClient` won't get you an instance of the client you have configured (How would the framework know that you want the client for the Product API? You have to tell the framework which client you want either by name or by type).

When using a named client you have to inject `IHttpClientFactory` and whenever you need a `HttpClient` call `_httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ProductApi")` which will get you an instance of the client (of type `HttpClient`) you configured using `AddHttpClient("ProductApi", ...)`.

Here is an example as provided by Microsoft:

```cs
public class NamedClientModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public NamedClientModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) =>
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

    public IEnumerable<GitHubBranch>? GitHubBranches { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("GitHub");
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(
            "repos/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/branches");

        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            
            GitHubBranches = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <IEnumerable<GitHubBranch>>(contentStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration of the named client in the `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");

    // using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
    // The GitHub API requires two headers.
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample");
});
```

For the original source of the examples and more detailed explanation please see [Microsoft Docs - Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests).